# How do I print numeric values with a string in R

Tags: r

I have a integer that has been assigned to a variable, I want to print that to the console but i get an error. Code and sample below

```
number <- 64
print("I want to print this number: " + number)
```

But instead I get the message: "*Error: non-numeric argument to binary operator*"
I want to see something like

```
[1] "I want to print this number: 64"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `sprintf`

```
sprintf("I want to print this number: %i", number)
#[1] "I want to print this number: 64"
```

or `paste0`

```
paste0("I want to print this number: ", number)
#[1] "I want to print this number: 64"
```

Comment: Is this 0 after paste a typo or intended?

Comment: "‘paste0(..., collapse)’ is equivalent to ‘paste(..., sep = "",
     collapse)’, slightly more efficiently."